# Ignore last specified character in a File

Tags: java

I have this section of code:

```
int numberStars =0;
int counter =0;

while (file.hasNext()) {
  String contents = file.next();
  {             
    if (contents.contains("*")) {
      numberStars = counter;                    
      continue;
    }
    counter++;              
  }
}
```

So if I have a text file containing something like

ha de fa * la we * ba *

The output will be 3,5,6.  How do I change this loop so that the last * is not counted (so the 6 won't be present), and also how would I ensure, that each time a value is assigned to numberStars, that value is then used in another part of the method?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might want to store a list of values of `counter` instead of just a single `int`.  Something like

```
List<Integer> numberStars = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int counter = 0;
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String contents = file.next();
    if (contents.contains("*")) {
        numbStars.add(counter);
        continue;
    }
    counter++;
}
numberStars.remove(numberStars.size() - 1); // remove last value
// all the values are now available in the numberStars list
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, then save the last counter, and at the end, use only it.

```
int lastcounter = -1;
boolean starfound = false;
while (file.hasNext()) {
  String contents = file.next();
  {             
    if (contents.contains("*")) {
      lastcounter = numberstars;
      numberStars = counter;
      starfound = true;                    
    } else {
      counter++;              
    }
    if(starfound) {
       // do something
       starfound = false;
    }
  }
}
return lastcounter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains the file only one line?
I would suggest to read the File with a BufferedReader and then
use the String.split() methode to find the number of stars.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile"));
String line;
String[] tmp;
int counter;

while( (line=br.readLine() ) !=null)
{
    tmp = line.split(" ");

    //Ignoring the last element
    for(int i = 0; i < (tmp.length-1); i++)
    {
          if(tmp[i].contains("*"))
              counter++;
    }


}
```